# Como posicionar o Modal no centro do ecrã?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Com a framework Bootstrap 4 como fazer para posicionar o Modal no centro da tela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está descrito na documentação oficial, no **modal-dialog** vc tem que incluir tb a classe **modal-dialog-centered** Leia aqui https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#vertically-centered

Segue o exemplo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
  
</style>
</head>
<body>
  
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado Geremias. Sou um novato nestas coisas...

Comment: @Jim Aproveita que está aprendendo, pega esse link ai da documentação e da uma boa lida, é bem tranquilo de entender as coisas e vai te ajudar muito no futuro. Se vc acha que a resposta resolveu ai, lembre-se de marca-la como aceita! Abs

Comment: Como é que eu faço isso?

Answer (score 0):

Adicione a classe `.modal-dialog-centered` dentro da div com classe `.modal-dialog`

Você também consegue retirar essas dúvidas acessando a documentação do bootstrap [clicando aqui](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/)